# jQuery Mobile Dialog Page - Fixed Position Header

Tags: jquery-mobile, dialog, fixed, scrollable

I can get fixed headers to work correctly on other pages but when I try to do it in a page that has `data-dialog="true"` it doesn't seem to work. Is this a limitation of the dialog box?

Note that I'm using the following CSS to allow for tall scrollable dialogs:

```
.ui-dialog-contain {
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow:hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

My Code is as follows:

```
<div data-role="page" data-dialog="true" id="dialog_page" >

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <!-- lots of content removed -->
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the max height and scrolling of the content div instead of the entire dialog:

```
.ui-dialog-contain .ui-content{
    max-height: 450px;
    overflow:hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Lgo55xgn/)**